# Group by calculated dates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "start_time" : ISODate("2017-08-22T19:43:41.442Z"), 
    "end_time" : ISODate("2017-08-22T19:44:22.150Z")
  },
  {
    "start_time" : ISODate("2017-08-22T19:44:08.344Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2017-08-22T19:46:25.500Z") 
  }
]
```

Is there any way to run an aggregation query that will give me a frequency result like:

```
{ 
   ISODate("2017-08-22T19:43:00.000Z"): 1,
   ISODate("2017-08-22T19:44:00.000Z"): 2,
   ISODate("2017-08-22T19:45:00.000Z"): 1,
   ISODate("2017-08-22T19:46:00.000Z"): 1
}
```

Essentially I want to group by minute, with a sum, but the trick is that each record might count toward multiple groups.  Additionally, as in the case with 19:45, the date is not explicitly mentioned in the data (it is calculated as being between two other dates).

At first I thought I could do this with a function like $minute.  I could group by minute and check to see if the data fits in that range.  However, I'm stuck on how that would be accomplished, if that's possible at all.  I'm not sure how to turn a single entry into multiple date groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6 mongo version.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{"date":["$start_time","$end_time"]}},
  {"$unwind":"$date"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{"$year":"$date"},
      "month":{"$month":"$date"},
      "day":{"$dayOfMonth":"$date"},
      "hour":{"$hour":"$date"},
      "minute":{"$minute":"$date"}
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$addFields":{
    "_id":{
      "$dateFromParts":{
        "year":"$_id.year",
        "month":"$_id.month",
        "day":"$_id.day",
        "minute":"$_id.minute"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  It is similar to my attempt only it works.  Still stuck on this idea of getting the values in between start_time and end_time, say the 19:45 of my example (which is not explicit in any start_time or end_time).  Not sure it's even possible.

Comment: Np. I'm afraid that is not going to be possible in aggregation framework. You will probably need to use map reduce.

Comment: Then I'll mark this as correct, especially considering it saves me the aggravation of continuing down this path for a solution that's not possible